# Facade does not implement getFacadeAccessor method

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error message after trying to downgrade laravel 9 to 8 cause i recently downgraded my php version from 8 to 7.3

```
In Facade.php line 178:
                                                   
Facade does not implement getFacadeAccessor method.  
                                                   

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump even
returned with error code 1
```

Comment: Have you implemented your **getFacadeAccessor**  method in your facade class?

Because This error occurs when you didn't implement  this method
 in your own facade class

Comment: I don't know where the Facade.php file is can't seem to find it

Comment: i have found the Facade.php but how do i implement it

Comment: if you check [this part in the laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/facades#how-facades-work), you can see the sample of the own facade class implementation.
when you extend the Facade class, you must implement the **getFacadeAccessor** method for using in-service container

Comment: Go this error while deploying a project after migrating from Laravel 8 to 9, while my local version was perfectly fine. Nothing could help, so I reset the project state on my server, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in `config/app.php` replace

```php
 'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([ ])->toArray(),
```

with:

```php
'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'Date' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Date::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Http' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::class,
        'Js' => Illuminate\Support\Js::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'RateLimiter' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        // 'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    ],
```

Comment: I was degrading php from 8.0 to 7.4 and this resolved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In my case the error started to appear, after run Laravel Shift to upgrade from 8.x to 9.x, where I've executed `composer install` instead `composer update`.

Then, I've deleted the vendor folder and run `composer update`.

Now everything is fine.

Comment: Also got this after Shift from 8.x to 9.x but in my case renaming vendor folder and composer update didn't work. I had to follow advice where aliases merge is replaced with actual alias. Also I have Laravel Nova so composer update has a bunch of other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Same for me after running Laravel Shift.
You probably have a dependency using an older version of illuminate/support.

You have to use an **illuminate/support** version >= 9

Simply add or update thie line in composer.json:

`"illuminate/support": "^9.46",`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was downgrading the php version to 8.0.1 was causing the issue.. however, updating to 8.0.2 and laravel/farmework to ^9.2 helped me to get rid of the error

Answer (score -4):

its because you forgot to run

php artisan ui vue --auth

after composer require laravel/ui

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).